# chrome-remote-desktop in fedora 27/28 or in wayland in general

Tags: linux, google-chrome, remote-desktop, fedora

I've got my desktop computer behind a NAT from internet provider without public IP and I still want to access the computer from outside world.

Has anyone succesfully configured chrome-remote-desktop in fedora 27/28?
I just installed the app from google repo to both client and host but in doesn't work.

Content of my .chrome-remote-desktop-session:

> exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session 'gnome-session --session=gnome-classic'

and when I try to enable sharing it says:

> /usr/lib64/chrome-remote-desktop/user-session not installed setuid root. Host must be started by administrator.

I've got lightdm installed (and I don't know how to start session with wayland) and chrome-remote-desktop version is 65.0.3325.181-1.fc28.x86_64

Have anyone been succesfull with making it work? Thanks a lot in advance!

**[update]**

> sudo chmod +s /usr/lib64/chrome-remote-desktop/user-session

solves this problem.

However the server the screen sharing still doesn't start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured it out myself - I've started session with Xorg (without wayland) and after that I was able to connect to the computer with .chrome-remote-desktop-session content:

> exec gnome-session